# Where to place the web admin folder?

Tags: php, security, admin

I have my website coded and almost ready for deployment. The only thing that am confused about is where to place the admin (backend) folder at for non visibility (scanners like acunetix) and security.

Currently, the admin folder is on the root folder like the image shown below

[image]

I read about "security through obscurity" and have a decent understanding about the topic. What I was thinking about (and never did or try before) creating a sub domain `www.admin.abc.com` and then uploading the admin content there.

Which one is the better way to go with?

Sincerely looking for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all files, admin or otherwise, if you don't want the webserver to map a URL directly onto a file then it should be kept out of the webroot entirely. Otherwise, it should probably go somewhere under the webroot.

The point of the security through obscurity issue is that you can't trust a trivial secret (like the URL) to protect it. It therefore doesn't really matter what the URL is (at least from a security point of view) and you can put it wherever is convenient. Just make sure you put some real security (such as password based authentication) in place.

Comment: In case if I put the admin folder out of webroot then how do I access the admin folder via a web browser.

Comment: @RivaanDaksh — You don't. See the "if" i the first sentence of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not wary about your backend folder location **IF** you have no vulnerabilities in your code.

If it is a private software, (not open source to public) then you have better chances, but while you still in your beginning of coding, you probably have many vulnerabilities.

Scanner software's can't discover any unlinked folders (no link in html source), unless by guessing for the most popular keywords.

- It is recommended to make the backend folder free to rename (no include from outside), and give it an uncommon name, even different one for each website.
- If you believe you might have code vulnerabilities, you can also protect that folder using Apache password protection.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can restrict the admin folder using HTTP Authentication, in this way hacker needs to bypass the http auth before he sees a login page. This should do the job to keep admin safe as well as apps like Acunetix will pass it.

In addition to above, you can ensure that admin is having HTTPS in order to prevent password hijacking.